# Update XML attributes using PHP, but result was "Can't use method return value in write context"

Tags: php, xml

I need your help. A little bit confuse on how to change the img src from given XML data.

The error was returned:

```
Can't use method return value in write context
```

How to solve this problem? Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks! Have a nice day!

```
<?php

$question_data = '<p>My questions here....</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><img class="img-responsive" src="/uploads/images/questions/93_20161017102613.jpg" style="max-height:400px;" /></p>';

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML($question_data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);


echo '<pre>';

//Initial Dom

//Find only image and convert url

//Process to convert url
$imgNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('img');


echo '<br/>';
$arr_image_file_names = [];

for ($i = $imgNodes->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $imgNode = $imgNodes->item($i);
    $image_file_names = pathinfo($imgNode->getAttribute('src'), PATHINFO_BASENAME);

    if(!empty($image_file_names)):
    // Replace with new src

    $imgNode->getAttribute('src') = 'http://myurl/qst/def/img/v1/'.$image_file_names;

    endif;
}

echo '<br/>';
echo htmlentities($xml->saveHTML());

//Update into new array


//Convert back to DOM


echo '</pre>';


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use instead the [`setAttribute` function](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php)

```
$imgNode->setAttribute('src', 'http://myurl/qst/def/img/v1/'.$image_file_names);
```

The result of the `getAttribute` function is a string (and not a variable), and you can't assign a new value to a string (or in this case - the returned value of the function).

Comment: Thanks! You save my days!.

Comment: Can you show me how to addAttribute? Is the same like:
`$imgNode->addAtribute('style','max-width:100%');` ?

Comment: no, it's the same with `setAttribute` the `setAttribute` adds the attribute if it doesn't exists.